# At which pole did Byrd's adventure take place?

Tags: richard-e-byrd, sld-of-adm-richard-e-byrd

*The Secret Lost Diary of Admiral Richard E. Byrd and The Phantom of the Poles* book describes a mysterious journey of Admiral Richard E. Byrd during his flight to the Polar region of the world.

In the brief description at the [Amazon website](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Secret-Diary-Admiral-Richard-Phantom/dp/160611137X) it's said he made a flight into the South Polar region. On another [website](http://www.thetruthseeker.co.uk/?p=7822) it's said the exploration flight was over the North Pole.

Then in the content of the book, it also keeps shifting from the North Pole to the South, and back again.

Therefore, at which pole did Admiral Byrd's alleged adventure take place?

Comment: From the preface - *"In the year 1947, Admiral Richard E. Byrd made a flight into the **South Polar region** of the world. Before he started on the venture, Byrd made a mysterious statement: ‘I’d like to see that land beyond the Pole. That area beyond the Pole in the center of the great unknown.’ In the cockpit of his plane was a powerful two-way radio. When Byrd and his scientific companions took off from their base at the South Pole, they managed to fly 1700 miles beyond it. That’s when the radio in Byrd’s plane was put into use to report something utterly incredible.”*"

Comment: @Valorum From the question - "*in the content of the book, it also keeps shifting from the North Pole to the South, and back again.*" Apparently your quote is only one of many in the text itself which contradict each other.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Indeed. Hence why I didn't post it as an answer. I don't have a copy of the book and while this excerpt seems conclusive, the wording of the question was sufficient to put me off.

Answer (score 1):

The full text on Amazon makes it clear that this is a Hollow Earth book. According to the myth (and that's all it is), there are holes in the Earth at both poles. They provide passage to another world inside our planet, which is hollow. Once inside, you can get out again through either hole, which explains the confusion. Byrd was definitely in Antarctica in February 1947, so it's the only way he could get to the Arctic with nobody noticing. That's an awful long way to go on one tank of gas, though.

Comment: "*The full text on Amazon makes it clear*" - please could you [edit] this answer to include some pertinent quotes? Without having read the book, I'm not understanding how this answers the question. Did Byrd go through the centre of the earth to travel between the poles? If so, how? (I'm sure you're *right*, just saying that as written this answer isn't yet doing a very good job of justifying itself. Also, please don't take this as discouragement! You've been posting some very nice answers, and clearly have a wide knowledge of literature - I really hope you stick around here :-) )